# Code taking too long- How to speed up

Tags: r, performance

I have this small piece of code in my script which is calculating several annotation for peak regions. The code below is bottleneck for speed and takes several hours as I have around 100,000 regions for which I need to run this to calculate CpG count. Is there a way to speed it up?

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dataMtx)){
peakCord<-gsub("chr", "", peakCord)
peakSeq<-system(sprintf("samtools faidx genome.fa %s", peakCord[i]), intern=T)
peakSeq<-gsub(">.*$", "", peakSeq)
peakSeq<-paste(peakSeq, collapse='')
dataMtx$CpGCount[i] <-  sum(str_count(peakSeq, "CG"))
print(i)
}
```

Comment: you can try use the `apply()` functions and its associated family. Probably want to be using data.table or dplyr packages if you are pushing for speed. Or write the function in c / compile it - although I have personally not tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. Not sure how much faster it'll be.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

result = 
  data_frame(peakCord = peakCord) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(peakCord.replace = 
           peakCord %>% 
           stri_replace_all_fixed("chr", ""),
         peakSeq = 
           peakCord.replace %>%
           sprintf("samtools faidx genome.fa %s", .) %>%
           system(intern = T) %>%
           stri_replace_all(">.*$", "") %>%
           paste(collapse=''),
         CpGCount = peakSeq %>% stri_count_fixed("CG") )
```

Comment: thanks bramtayl.. I think as I have even more regions now (around 500,000) and doing in R in a for loop is really slow as populating table on the fly also makes it slow. So, I ended up writing a perl script for same. I could do the job in about in hour for 300,000 regions unlike 4 days taken by R loop. Thanks anyway for nice suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I ended up doing as mentioned above by perk code. In case anyone need it. Code will not only count number of CpGs but also their postions and will also add GC percent.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN { our $start_run = time(); }

open(POSITIONS,"mergedPeaks.bed"); # "mergedPeaks.bed");
my $filename='outfile.txt';
open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
my $string1="CG";
my @positions=();
while(<POSITIONS>){
chomp;
unless($_=~ m/^chrom/){
my ($seqName,$begin,$end) = split(/\t/);
$seqName=~s/chr//;
open(SAMTOOLS,"samtools faidx /n/meissnerfs2/Everyone/sthakurela/annotationFiles/genomeFASTA/hs/hg19/genome.fa $seqName:$begin-$end |");
my @data = <SAMTOOLS>;
chop(@data);
my $seq=join("", @data);
$seq =~ s/\d+|\:|\-//g;
while ($seq =~ /$string1/gi ){
push(@positions, pos($seq)- length($string1));
}
my $length=scalar @positions;
my $seqLen=length($seq);
my $GC_count=($seq=~tr/GC/GC/);
my $GCper=sprintf("%.2f", ($GC_count/$seqLen)*100);
print $fh $_, "\t", $length,"\t", (join(",",@positions)), "\t", $GCper, "\n";
@positions=();
@data=();
$GC_count=0;
$GCper=0;
$seqLen=0;
close(SAMTOOLS);
}}
close(POSITIONS);
close $fh;

my $end_run = time();
my $run_time = $end_run - our $start_run;
print "Job took $run_time seconds\n";
```